# Read environment variable in make file

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I have a environment variable set with name $MY_ENV_VARIABLE.

How do I use this variable inside my makefile to (for example) include some source files?

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = $(MY_ENV_VARIABLE)/libDEMO.so
```

Something like above doesn't seem to work.

Note: in my case this is needed for building with the Android NDK but I guess this applies to make in general.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure the variable is set?

Comment: @Sander , you variable declared should work. you could also try := instead of = and remove the spaces ... also have you tried the -e option in your make invocation ?  , -e : it forces the enviornment variables to take precedence ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you exported the variable from your shell.  Running:

```
echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE
```

shows you whether it's set in your shell.  But to know whether you've exported it so that subshells and other sub-commands (like make) can see it try running:

```
env | grep MY_ENV_VARIABLE
```

If it's not there, be sure to run `export MY_ENV_VARIABLE` before running make.

That's all you need to do: make automatically imports all environment variables as make variables when it starts up.

Comment: In `csh` it's `setenv MY_VAR my_val`

Answer (score 18):

Just to add some information...

The syntax to access the environment variable in make is like other variables in make...

```
#export the variable. e.g. in the terminal,
export MY_ENV_VARIABLE="hello world"

...

#in the makefile (replace before call)
echo $(MY_ENV_VARIABLE)
```

This performs the substitution before executing the commmand. If you instead, want the substitution to happen during the command execution, you need to escape the `$` (For example, `echo $MY_ENV_VARIABLE` is incorrect and will attempt to substitute the variable `M` in make, and append it to `Y_ENV_VARIABLE`)...

```
#in the makefile (replace during call)
echo $$MY_ENV_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue (under Cygwin):

- Running `echo $OSTYPE` on the shell prints the value, but
- running `env | grep OSTYPE` doesn't give any output.

As I can't guarantee that this variable is `export`ed on all machines I want to run that makefile on, I used the following to get the variable from within the makefile:

```
OSTYPE = $(shell echo $$OSTYPE)
```

Which of course can also be used within a condition like the following:

```
ifeq ($(shell echo $$OSTYPE),cygwin)
# ...do something...
else
# ...do something else...
endif
```

**EDIT:**

Some things I found after experimenting with the info from [jozxyqk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487089/897968), all from within the makefile:

- If I run `@echo $$OSTYPE` or `@echo "$$OSTYPE"` in a recipe, the variable is successfully expanded into `cygwin`.
- However, using that in a condition like `ifeq ($$OSTYPE,cygwin)` or `ifeq ("$$OSTYPE","cygwin")` doesn't expand it.
- Thus it is logical that first setting a variable like `TEST = "$$OSTYPE"` will lead to `echo $(TEST)` printing `cygwin` (the expansion is done by the `echo` call) but that doesn't work in a condition - `ifeq ($(TEST),cygwin)` is false.